# JDK 7 with Quartz version 2.3.1 throw exceptoin

Tags: java, quartz

In my project, there is no Maven or library management tool. I have to download jar from maven repository and then add it the Eclipse build path. Recently, I wanted to use Quartz version 2.3.1. For this, I downloaded 3 jar quartz-2.3.1.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, slf4j-jdk14-1.7.25.jar.

For the following code, it throws an exception:-

```
    public static void SchedulerDemo() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Config SchedulerDemo start");
        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(); // exceptoin in this line
        Scheduler scheduler = sf.getScheduler();

        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class).withIdentity("JobName", "GroupName").build();

        Date startTime = DateBuilder.nextGivenSecondDate(null, 10);

        CronTrigger crontrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("FiveSec", "GroupName").startAt(startTime).startNow().withSchedule(
            // run every 5 seconds infinite loop
            CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/05 * * * * ?")).build();
            // Only run once everyweek on Sunday
        // CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(" 0 0 10 ? * SUN *")).build();
            // For testing every Turesday at 14:30.
        // CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 2 30 ? * THU *").build();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, crontrigger);
        System.out.println("Config SchedulerDemo end");

        // scheduler.shutdown();

    } catch (SchedulerException se) {
        // se.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(" SchedulerException Excption ex. " + se.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" SchedulerException Excption ex. " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

> Unhandled exception Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00000000
>   Windows_ExceptionCode=c00000fd J9Generic_Signal=00000004
>   ExceptionAddress=00007FFF7377AA35 ContextFlags=0010005f
>   Handler1=00007FFF7377DDA0 Handler2=00007FFF807F5860
>   RDI=0000000000000000 RSI=0000000004020700 RAX=0000000025504060
>   RBX=0000000025505610 RCX=0000000004020700 RDX=00000000061BE750
>   R8=0000000000000092 R9=0000000000000000 R10=0000000012FAED28
>   R11=00000000000000F2 R12=0000000003303500 R13=0000000000000092
>   R14=00000000061BE750 R15=0000000000000002 RIP=00007FFF7377AA35
>   RSP=0000000025503E30 RBP=0000000000000000 GS=002B FS=0053 ES=002B
>   DS=002B XMM0 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000) XMM1
>   0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000) XMM2 0000000000000000
>   (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000) XMM3 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d:
>   0.000000e+000) XMM4 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000) XMM5 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000) XMM6
>   0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000) XMM7 0000000000000000
>   (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000) XMM8 000000003f800000 (f:
>   1065353216.000000, d: 5.263544e-315) XMM9 000000003f800000 (f: 1065353216.000000, d: 5.263544e-315) XMM10 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000) XMM11 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000) XMM12 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000) XMM13 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000) XMM14
>   0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000) XMM15
>   0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000)
>   Module=C:\JavaDev\tools\java\jre\bin\compressedrefs\j9vm28.dll
>   Module_base_address=00007FFF73750000 Offset_in_DLL=000000000002aa35
>   Target=2_80_20150630_255633 (Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 build 17763)
>   CPU=amd64 (8 logical CPUs) (0x7faf9d000 RAM)
>   ----------- Stack Backtrace -----------

What did I miss? I have never seen such exception? Please let me know what is wrong?

Comment: Seg fault appears to be a very bad, C-like error.  I would recommend that you upgrade to JDK 8 immediately and not use Quartz.  There are alternatives built into java.util.concurrency now.  JDK 7 is long past the end of its support life.

Comment: Can you download the jar files once again and try ?

Comment: I can't upgrade to JDK 8 any time soon. I have to find a compatible version of Quartz for JDK7. Do you know which version of Quartz is for JDK7?  Thanks!

Comment: You can check the jdk compatibility here http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.3.1-SNAPSHOT/changelog.html

Comment: For testing, I used a JDK8 in a demo console app. I get the same exception for the mentioned qurerzt library. What could be wrong.